# Three.js SceneUtils has no traverseHierarchy!!! where is it?

Tags: three.js, webgl, updates

I had not updated the three.js library in my system. Today, I updated the three.js file. But I encountered this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'traverseHierarchy' ".

I had used it for detecting intersection:
Online code is here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44791710/test/simple2.html

```
function Intersect(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var mousex = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    var mousey = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mousex, mousey, 1);

    var toIntersect = [];
    THREE.SceneUtils.traverseHierarchy(scene, function (child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            toIntersect.push(child);
        }
    });
    var projector = new THREE.Projector();
    projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);
    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position,vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());
    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(toIntersect);
    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        for (var j = 0; j < intersects.length ; j++){
                target = intersects[j].object;
                console.log('Intersects at ' + mouse.x + '/' + mouse.y + ':');
                for(var i = 0, m = intersects.length; i<m; i++){
                     console.log(intersects[i].object.id, intersects[i]);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

what kind of changes I need to do?
Thanks.

Comment: It is called traverse() hanging off Object3D.

Comment: I am newbie and did not understand what you mean! Would you please elaborate it more?! I checked THREE.SceneUtils and THREE.Object3D but there is no any traverse()!!! Thanks.

Comment: If you look at the documentation at http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/57/#Reference/Core/Object3D you will see the traverse() function there as a method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should replace `scene.traverse(scene, function (child) {` by `scene.traverse(function (child) {` (I could not add a comment, so I created an answer instead).

Answer (score 2):

As the [Migration](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) guide states, in r51 -> r52:

> Replaced SceneUtils.traverseHierarchy with object.traverse.

`object` meaning any `THREE.Object3D` instance, e.g. `THREE.Mesh` or `THREE.Scene`. So instead of `THREE.SceneUtils.traverseHierarchy`, try `scene.traverse`.

Comment: I replaced the THREE.SceneUtils.traverseHierarchy,BY scene.traverse. But I got this error!! Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function!!! Please have a look to the online code here https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44791710/test/simple2.html   many thanks!!!

Comment: @mbehnaam Since it's a member function, you don't pass the scene as a parameter, only the callback. See the API docs gaitat linked in the question comments.